# how to add single item to drop area without adding multiple items

Tags: html

**Following is the code used for implementing dynamic listing along with drag and drop functionality**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script>
            function allowDrop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev) {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            }

            function drop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                var dragDiv = document.getElementById(data);
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                console.log(document.getElementById(data));
            }

            $( "#send" ).on( "click", function() {

            $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'http://localhost:8080/sample.json',
              success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
              }
            }); 

          $('#maindiv').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');

          $.getJSON('sample.json', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.items, function (i, data) {
                var div_data = "<option value=" + data.value + ">" + data.name + "</option>";
                $(div_data).appendTo('#dropdown1');
            }); 
          });

          $.getJSON('sample2.json', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.items, function (i, data) {
                var div_data = "<option value=" + data.value + ">" + data.name + "</option>";
                $(div_data).appendTo('#dropdown2');
            }); 
          });  

          $.getJSON('sample3.json', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.items, function (i, data) {
                var div_data = "<option value=" + data.value + ">" + data.name + "</option>";
                $(div_data).appendTo('#dropdown3');
            }); 
          });  

        }); 


        $('#btn-submit').on('click', function(){

            if (!$('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
                alert('not valid');
            }else{
                $('#maindiv').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
                $('#drag-drop').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');       
            }
        });     


        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input id="send" type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                </div>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button id="test" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="maindiv" class="row hide"> 
          <form>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="dropdown1" required>
                    </select>
                  </div>        
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="dropdown2" required>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="dropdown3" required>
                    </select>
                  </div>        
                </div>      
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <label for="ex3">col-xs-4</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="ex3" type="text" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <label for="ex3">col-xs-4</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="ex3" type="text" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
                </div>            
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="row">
                    Test
                </div>
            </div>      
          </form>
        </div>

        <div id="drag-drop" class="row hide">
            <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid grey;"></div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <p data-price="10" id="drag1" draggable="true" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Price: 10</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                <p data-price="10" id="drag2" draggable="true" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Price: 20</p>
                </li>   
                <li>
                <p data-price="10" id="drag3" draggable="true" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Price: 30</p>
                </li>           
            </ul>       
        </div>  

        </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**I am using html5 drag and drop functionality for dropping items, currently its is appending to drop container. I want to keep the last dropped items in the drop container. This i need to implement with validation**